# Windows Home Server backup status stuck at 0%

Tags: backup, windows-home-server

Only one of the six computers I have connected to the WHS will not complete a backup. The status window stays at 0% forever.

Comment: Windows Home Server? How are they connected (are they)? What versions of Windows do they all run? Please add some more info!

Answer (score 0):

Try each of these, in order

- Reboot the client PC
- Reboot the home server
- Run CHKDSK on the client PC
- Run Backup Repair on the server:
  [image: WHS Backup Repair]
- Delete your backup database. (You may want to make a copy of it first. Check out BDBB http://www.mswhs.com/2009/04/add-in-windows-home-server-backup-database-backup-bdbb-1016/ )